# Bash linux (WSL) on windows 10 - terminal/console not refreshing the folder/file when i move something in it

Tags: linux, windows, bash, directory, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So, like I said in the title, I'm using a bash linux on windows, and I'm using Cmder.

But, when I open the directory on Explorer, and I create/move/remove a file or a folder, or whatever inside the folder. The new file is not listed in the "ls" console command, i can't even execute it. It's return "No such file or directory".

I need to 'logout' and re-bash to refresh the directory.

The only way to have the same elements in the folder(explorer) and in the bash, is to create/remove/etc by cmd(mv/touch/rm/etc..).

But it's a bit tidious sometimes when I need to move a lot of file from a download or something.

Do someone know how to do for me to refresh the directory in the bash, automatically ?

[Before adding a new file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFmyJ.png)

```
ls -la
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 sili sili 4096 Jun  1 18:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 sili sili 4096 Jun  1 18:38 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 sili sili    0 Jun  1 18:37 info.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 sili sili    0 Jun  1 18:37 test.sql
-rw-rw-rw- 1 sili sili    0 Jun  1 18:37 text.txr
```

[After creating new elements in the folder(explorer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwH7t.png)

```
:~/SQL$ ls -la
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 sili sili 4096 Jun  1 18:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 sili sili 4096 Jun  1 18:38 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 sili sili    0 Jun  1 18:37 info.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 sili sili    0 Jun  1 18:37 test.sql
-rw-rw-rw- 1 sili sili    0 Jun  1 18:37 text.txr
```

So nothing's updated in the bash.

Comment: WSL?  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/

Comment: Also this is a question for Superuser, since stackoverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Oh man, thanks a lot, exactly what i needed, quick answer aswell, you're a god.
Also, how can i mark you as the "answer post" to close the topic ?

Comment: I added as an an actual answer and you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If on WSL, modifications from Windows tools **must** be done in the Windows file system (`/mnt/c/SharedWSLFiles`/`c:\SharedWSLFiles`, for example).  More to the point, Windows Tools should not be used in the Linux FS.  This is okay since Ubuntu can work with the Windows FS.  This is a hard and fast rule, per MS:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/